# What is the Difference Between a Version and a Modification of a Stochastic Process?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, soft-question, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Under what circumstances would one say that:

> The stochastic process $X$ is a ***version*** of the stochastic
>   process $Y$?

---

**Background:** See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150297/difference-between-modification-and-indistinguishable) for a related but slightly different question on Math.SE.

Usually the word version is used most often in connection with conditional expectations, or general random variables, to mean that:

> The random variable $X$ is a ***version*** of the random variable $Y$ iff: $$\mathbb{P}[X=Y]=1,$$ i.e $X=Y$ almost surely.

I have also heard the term used in reference to stochastic processes, but in this case I am not sure how it should be used, and how it relates to the terms ***modification*** and ***indistinguishable***.

> Let $X,Y$ be random functions (i.e. stochastic processes) mapping from the index set $T$ to a measurable space $\Omega$.
>
> $X$ is a ***modification*** of $Y$ iff $$\forall\ t\in T,\ \mathbb{P}[X(t)=Y(t)]=1$$ and $X$ is ***indistinguishable*** from $Y$ iff $$\mathbb{P}[X(t)=Y(t),\ \forall\ t \in T]=1.$$

Note here the different placements of the logical quantifier $$\forall\ t\in T$$ outside vs. inside the definition of the set whose probability is in question between the two definitions.

However, under what circumstances would we say that:

> The stochastic process $X$ is a ***version*** of the stochastic
>   process $Y$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is really subtle. Citing *Jeanblanc,Yor,Chesney* (2009), they give the two following definitions:

> The process X is a **modification** of Y if $\forall t$ $\mathbb{P}(X_t=Y_t)=1$.
>
> The process X is **indistinguishable from** (or a **version**) of Y if {$\omega: X_t(\omega)=Y_t(\omega),\forall t$} is a measurable set and $\mathbb{P}(X_t=Y_t,\forall t)=1$

They moreover add the following relation: if $X$ and $Y$ are modifications of each other and are a.s. continuous, they are indistinguishable.

EDIT: There is an even more clear definition and explanation of the relation between the different definitions looking in *Karatzas&Shreve* (1998), p.2. Check it at this [link](https://books.google.it/books?id=ATNy_Zg3PSsC&pg=PA1&hl=it&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: So is indistinguishability the true "analog" of one-dimensional functions being versions of each other (i.e. almost everywhere equal)?

Comment: Also do you know how this relates to "versions" of conditional distributions? (For example, "regular versions"?) I should probably ask this as a separate question shouldn't I?

Comment: Also then some people define "version" as two stochastic processes with the same distribution, where distribution refers to the finite-dimensional distributions which is equivalent to being a modification -- wait so is being a modification like "being equal in distribution" and being indistinguishable is "being equal almost surely"? Because then this definition makes more sense.

Comment: Regarding the first question, I think so, because there is the additional requirement of measurability of the path for indistinguishability. And in that case what you wrote in this last comment makes complete sense.

Comment: So in practice if $X$ and $Y$ are indistinguishable, it means almost all their sample paths agree. This implies that $X$ and $Y$ are modifications of each other, which in turn implies they have the same finite-dimensional distributions.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! This really clears things up for me, and I've been having difficulty understanding this for a while.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A_t = \{X(t)=Y(t)\}$ to see how we can generalise this.

$X$ is a ***modification*** of $Y$ iff $$\forall\ t\in T,\ \mathbb{P}[A_t]=1$$ and $X$ is ***indistinguishable*** from $Y$ iff $$\mathbb{P}[\bigcap_{t \in T} A_t]=1.$$

Remark: There's actually no difference if $T$ is countable.

Comment: I really like the way you wrote this -- it makes the difference very visible/visually clear. So it's a difference in the position of the quantifiers it seems. I guess similar to the difference between uniformly continuous and equicontinuous or something like that https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195848/whats-equicontinuous-whats-uniform-equicontinuous-whats-pointwise-equiconti

Comment: @Chill2Macht I had the same idea of using $\bigcap$ to understand uniform continuity the other day

Comment: @Chill2Macht WHO ARE YOU XD

Comment: That's a somewhat random question isn't it

Comment: @Chill2Macht it's a joke. Like it's as if you're me from the future or another dimension (crickets chirp)

Comment: Oh well I always just figured that similar minds tend to cluster around Math.SE due to essentially natural selection. I get it now anyway now that you have explained it -- I thought you were literally asking, and was somewhat freaked out.

Comment: I don't get your definition $A_t = \{X(t)=Y(t)\}$. It's a set of what? Do you mean $ \{w\in\Omega\colon X(t)=Y(t)\}$?

Comment: I simply means that the answer could be better if elaborating a bit.

Comment: Can you give me an example where $X$ is a modification of $Y$, but $X$ and $Y$ are not indistinguishable?