# Meaning of "with probability approaching $1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$"

Tags: limits, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

I have a question on the meaning of this claim:

Consider a sequence of real valued random variables $\{X_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and some constants $a,b$. Then we have

$$
\sqrt{n}a\leq X_{n}\leq \sqrt{n}b \text{ }\text{ with probability approaching $1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$}
$$

---

Specifically, I am confused on the meaning of "with probability approaching $1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$" and an help to clarify it would be extremely helpful.

---

I know that writing $X_n$ converges to $X$ with probability approaching $1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ is equivalent to $X_n\rightarrow_{a.s.}X$, i.e., 
$$
\mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega \text{ s.t. } \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)\})=1
$$
but the claim above contains inequalities. Do they mean
$$
\mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega \text{ s.t. } \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} [X_n(\omega)-\sqrt{n}b]\leq 0\})=1
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega \text{ s.t. } \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} [X_n(\omega)-\sqrt{n}a]\geq 0\})=1
$$
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that
$$
\lim _{n\to\infty} P(\{\omega\mid \sqrt{n}a\leq X_n(w)\leq \sqrt{n} b\})=1
$$

Comment: Thank you. Then I guess that also my point about equivalence between "$X_n$ converges to $X$ with probability approaching $1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$" and almost sure convergence was wrong?

Comment: @CGT See my answer

Answer (score 1):

No. It's this one: $$
\lim _{n\to\infty} P(C_n)=1
$$

where

$$C_n := \{ \sqrt{n}a\leq X_n(w)\leq \sqrt{n} b \}$$

$$= \{ \sqrt{n}a\leq X_n(w)\} \cap \{X_n(w)\leq \sqrt{n} b \}$$

$$:= A_n \cap B_n$$

Thus, $$C_n \subseteq A_n, C_n \subseteq B_n$$

$$\to P(C_n) \le P(A_n), P(C_n) \le P(B_n)$$

$$\to \lim_n P(C_n) \le \lim_n P(A_n), \lim_n P(C_n) \le \lim_n P(B_n)$$

Thus when you say

> $$ \mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega \text{ s.t. } \lim_{n\rightarrow
>  \infty} [X_n(\omega)-\sqrt{n}b]\leq 0\})=1 $$ and $$
>  \mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega \text{ s.t. } \lim_{n\rightarrow
>  \infty} [X_n(\omega)-\sqrt{n}a]\geq 0\})=1 $$

, you are saying something weaker namely merely that $\lim_n P(A_n) = 1 = \lim_n P(B_n)$. Here, it could be that $\lim_n P(C_n) < 1$.

Intuitively, I guess that there isn't a common way that $n$ approaches $\infty$. Do you know/Have you heard of [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) ?

Anyhoo, a similar problem arises in comparing

$$P(\bigcap_{n \in T} A_n) = 1$$

$$P(A_n) = 1 \ \forall n \in T$$

Do you know [modification vs indistinguishable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784571)?

Comment: There is another difference with what I wrote: in my case the limit is inside the probability, in your case it is outside. Could you comment on that too?

Comment: In my case I mimic almost sure convergence (limit inside the probability). In your case you have a sequence of probabilities.

Comment: @CGT Oh, right. Then in that case yours is worse actually, no offense: It is more wrong to say $$P(\lim_n [X_n - \sqrt{nb}] \le 0) = 1$$ than it is to say $$P(\lim_n [X_n - \sqrt{nb} \le 0]) = 1$$. At least the latter has an inclusion relationship with $$\lim_nP( [X_n - \sqrt{nb} \le 0]) = 1$$. The former: I'm not sure the limit even exists.

Comment: Thanks but your first two probabilities are the same. Could you explain better?

Comment: @CGT Which two probabilities? $$P(\lim_n [X_n - \sqrt{nb}\color{red}{]} \le 0) \ne P(\lim_n [X_n - \sqrt{nb} \le 0 \color{red}{]})$$ $$'\lim_n [X_n - \sqrt{nb}\color{red}{]} \le 0'$$ is the event that the random variable $$'\lim_n [X_n - \sqrt{nb}\color{red}{]}'$$ is less than or equal to zero. $$'\lim_n [X_n - \sqrt{nb} \le 0 \color{red}{]}'$$ is the limit of the events $[X_n - \sqrt{nb} \le 0 \color{red}{]}$